# Partial derivatives of matrix logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I am trying to figure out what the derivative of the matrix logarithm w.r.t. the matrix parameter is. So, for $X \in \mathcal S$ the set of $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite full-rank matrices, I'd like to find:
$$X \mapsto \frac {\partial \log(X)_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial X_{ij}},$$
and even if possible:
$$\frac {\partial \log(f(X))_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial X_{ij}}$$
for a given $f : \mathcal S \to \mathcal S$.

I tried a few things using the fact that if $X = V\Lambda V^\top$, then $\log X = V\log\Lambda V^\top$, but I haven't been able to make anything useful out of it since I know how to differentiate neither $V$ nor $\Lambda$ w.r.t. $X$. Any leads?

For a bit of context, I am reading [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/820475/filename/BARACHANT_Neurocomputing_ForHal.pdf) in which the authors use the matrix logarithm to locally map covariance matrices onto the tangent space to the SPD matrices manifold at a given point. I am trying to find how the original components of the covariance matrices affect the components of the *projected* matrix. Therefore I'd like to differentiate the mapping as shown above.

Using the power series expression of matrix log:
$$\log X = \sum_{m \geq 1}(-1)^{m+1}\frac 1m(X-I)^m$$
as a basis to differentiate formally yields:
$$\frac {\partial \log(X)_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial X_{ij}} = \sum_{m \geq 0}(-1)^{m+1}\frac 1m\frac {\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}{(X-I)^m}_{k\ell} = \sum_{m \geq 1}(-1)^{m+1}\frac 1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{(X-I)^k}_{\alpha i}{(X-I)^{m-1-k}}_{j\beta},$$
but again I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Doesn't "positive definite" imply "full-rank"?

Comment: Tried using the Taylor expansion of $\log$?

Comment: For Taylor, don't we need $||X-I|| < 1$? Because I am not sure it holds for any matrix in $\mathcal S$.

Comment: Call it power series instead. No need to worry about convergence yet. For example, one works with the power series for the matrix exponential without worrying if it converges.

Comment: Why do you need the $4$-dimensional matrix of derivatives?

Comment: All right, I'll look if something comes out by differentiating formally the series, though I don't quite understand why the result should be of interest if the series does not converge. And I need this because it appears in a chainrule differentiation

Comment: Generally speaking, the more information you provide on background and motivation, the better. Sometimes, answering the question as stated is very hard, but massaging it a bit (knowing where it comes from) may produce something that is actually tractable.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I edited the post to provide some context and where I am stuck regarding the power series.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 4th order tensors, it is usually easier to use vectorization in these situations.
$$\eqalign{
Y &= AXB \\
dY &= A\;dX\;B \\
{\rm vec}(dY) &= (B^T\otimes A)\;{\rm vec}(dX) \\
dy &= (B^T\otimes A)\;dx \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

For the current problem, define the symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
Z &= (X-I),\quad dZ = dX \\
Y &= \log(X) \;=\; \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\;Z^m \\
}$$
Then differentiate the power series and vectorize it.
$$\eqalign{
dY &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}
\;\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}Z^{k}\;dX\;Z^{m-1-k} \\ 
dy &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}
\;\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\Big(Z^{m-1-k}\otimes Z^{k}\Big)\;dx \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}
\;\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\Big(Z^{m-1-k}\otimes Z^{k}\Big) \\
}$$
Elements of the vector expression are **equal** to those of the tensor expression
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial y_{k}}{\partial x_{r}}
&= \frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial X_{pq}} 
}$$
The mapping for the vector indexes is given by
$$k = i + (j-1)n \\ r = p + (q-1)n \\$$

### Update #2

The gradient of $X$ with respect to one of its components is
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad{X}{X_{ij}} = E_{ij} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$ component equals one
and all other components equal zero.

The $\sf Daleckii$-$\sf Krein$ theorem, using an eigenvalue decomposition of $X$, states that
$$\eqalign{
\def\op{\operatorname}
\def\L{{\Lambda}}
\def\l{\lambda}
X &= V\L V^T, \qquad \L = \op{Diag}(\l_k) \\
F &= f(X) \;=\; V\,f(\L)\,V^T \\
dF &= V\,\Big[R\odot\left(V^TdX\,V\right)\Big]\,V^T \\
\\
R_{k\ell} &= \begin{cases}
  {\large\frac{f(\l_k)\,-\,f(\l_\ell)}{\l_k\,-\,\l_\ell}}\qquad{\rm if}\;\l_k\ne\l_\ell \\
\\
  \quad{\small f'(\l_k)}\qquad\qquad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the Hadamard product, and in the current problem the function of interest is
$$f(\l) = \log(\l), \qquad\quad f'(\l) = \l^{-1} \\ $$

Combining these two results produces a closed-form solution for the current problem
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\log(X)}{X_{ij}} &= V\,\Big[R\odot\left(V^TE_{ij}V\right)\Big]\,V^T \\
}$$

Comment: About the update, since the coefficients $c_0, \ldots, c_{n-1}$ depend on the matrix $X$, when taking the derivative wrt a $X_{\alpha\beta}$ coordinate, don't I need to take the derivative of these coefficients at some point?

Comment: If you're given an arbitrary polynomial function $p(X)=\sum c_mX^m$ and asked to find its derivative, I presume you'd have no problem with the calculation. Now it just so happens that at the point $X$ in ${\cal S}$, the logarithm is _identical_ to this particular fixed-degree polynomial, and the derivative that you calculated $p'(X)$ is valid -- but only at the point $X.\;$ A different point $Y\in{\cal S}$ will yield a completely different polynomial and derivative.

Comment: Why is it that the derivative of the polynomial is equal to the derivative of the log at point $X \in \mathcal S$? Doesn't that require $p$ and $\log$ to be equal on an open set around $X$?

Comment: @greg , the update does not work because $\log(X+H)=\sum c_m(X+H)(X+H)^m$.

Comment: You're right.  The update has been removed.